# Why peaks (of same order) in X-ray diffraction have different intensity?

Tags: diffraction, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

[image]

The image shows the intensity vs 2-theta plot of X-Ray diffraction pattern obtained from an aluminium target. Why is it so that as the 2-theta increases the peak intensity decreases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intensity depends on a number of factors, mainly the structure factor, multiplicity of plane, Lorentz factor, polarization factor, temperature and absorption factors. Combination of all these factors results in intensity variation.

To simplify things a bit, the most important factors relevant to your question are the [Lorentz factor](http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/diff2/loren.htm) and [polarization factors](http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/diff2/polar.htm). If you follow the links, you'll find simple angular relations for these factors, which should answer your question.